# Как вывести данные из базы в формате JSON

Tags: php

Вывожу данные из базы в виде "JSON"

```
echo '[';

$sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `id`, `category`, `cb_title` FROM `catalog` LIMIT 0,3');
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
$string = "{\"title\":\"{$result['cb_title']}\",\"hasAd\":false},";

}

echo ']';
```

На выходе получаю строки

```
[{"title":"{$result['cb_title']}","hasAd":false},
{"title":"{$result['cb_title']}","hasAd":false},
{"title":"{$result['cb_title']}","hasAd":false},]
```

Как удалить запятую перед закрывающим `,]`?

Использовал `$string = rtrim($string, ',');` - удаляет все запятые после всех `false},`

Спасибо!

Comment: И что будет, если в title окажется кавычка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так

```
echo substr($string,0,-1); или echo substr($string,0,-2).']';
```

или так

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $string[] = "{\"title\":\"{$result['cb_title']}\",\"hasAd\":false}";
}

echo implode(',',$string);
```

Comment: Здорово! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Вообще-то json_encode уже изобрели.

Answer (score 5):

Для этого есть более правильное решение, а именно использование `json_encode`. И не нужно никаких обрезаний строк.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `id`, `category`, `cb_title` FROM `catalog` LIMIT 0,3');

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $array[] = array('title' => $result['cb_title'], 'hasAd' => false);

}

$result = json_encode($array);
```